# IDE's (Integrated Development Environments) geared towards Web Development, for OS X

Tags: osx, web-development, ide, programming

I'm looking for [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) products (Integrated Development Environments) geared towards Web Development, for OS X. Specifically, I would need it to support:

- Ruby on Rails and/or
- Python
- PHP (least important)
- Debugging (in the browser, and with the ability to set breakpoints and step through code - debugging support is essential)
- Customizable Syntax Highlighting for all supported languages
- Publish/Deploy (preferred but not essential)

These are just the most important features I can think of right now, but I would like to list ones that I am not or no longer interested in:

- [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)
- [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/)
- [Adobe Brackets](http://brackets.io/)
- [Atom](https://atom.io/)
- [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

I can't remember the other ones I don't like. I don't really care how unpopular an IDE is, if you think it's worth mentioning, please do.

Also, it should be free, or at-least have a trial version/shareware version.

Comment: You should describe your criteria. Why did you reject the products on your list? Stack Exchange Question/Answers are meant to be a valuable nugget of thoughtful info, like a Wikipedia page, not a passing-thought forum thread.

Comment: You should link any mentioned product, or at least mention the publisher or full title.

Comment: Please note that "list-type" questions/answers are frowned upon on pretty much all SE sites. You will probably end up using ***one*** product anyway (and not multiple). Plus, we usually are not recommending "the worst", so no need to ask for "the best"; both are pretty subjective: what's best for you might be worst for someone else :) I've adjusted your question slightly to better match this site, hope you don't mind. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at the [Eric IDE](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/):

From your list:

- Mac - Yes & Windows & Linux
- Ruby on Rails and/or Python PHP (least important) - Written for Ruby & Python
- Debugging (in the browser, and with the ability to set breakpoints and step through code - debugging support is essential) - Yes
- Customizable Syntax Highlighting for all supported languages - Yes
- Publish/Deploy (preferred but not essential) - You may need to add a plugin

More:

- Spell Check
- Style Check
- VCS integration for CVS, Subversion and Mercurial via plugins
- Code folding
- Documentation Generator
- Integrated profiling and code coverage support
- Task management/ToDo list
- Python & Ruby interactive shells
- Integrated web browser
- Bug reporting integration
- Icon Editor
- *lots more*

The only downside is that there are a few dependencies to download and install/build for some platforms with QT taking the longest, (but also being well worth having).